# Windows command line: how to start a program in a specific folder

Tags: c++, command-line, windows-10

I need to start a program (ChaosLauncher for StarCraft) for a C++ program using the "system" command, but ChaosLauncher needs to start from another directory :[image: ChaosLauncher properties]

How can I do that in C++?
Or via the command line?

I previously used an AutoIt script but it stopped working when I updated to Windows 10...

Comment: [sigh] programs that use a 'current directory' :(

Comment: From code that has access to the Win32 API, call [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
system("start \"Chaos\" /D \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BWAPI\\Chaoslauncher\\\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BWAPI\\Chaoslauncher\\Chaoslauncher.exe\"");
```

Using the "start" command, /D to specify the directory from where the program should be launched

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this should be fairly simple.
Run cmd.exe as admin, the use

```
cd [your_directory]
```

to change the current working directory to where you want to launch the program from. Next simply launch the program as you have before (you'll probably need to specify the .exe's absolute path though).

Comment: It's rather sad that programs, especially Windows programs, still need a 'current directory':((

Comment: It does seem a little arcane. But it is a paradigm shared by Unix based systems as well.